# Comparing lists with every record in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a use case where I am comparing the list in same column with itself, code Below:

```
for i in range(0,len(counts95)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(counts95)):
        for x in counts95['links'][i]:
            for y in counts95['links'][j]:
                if x == y and counts95['linkoflinks'][j] is None:
                    counts95['linkoflinks'][j] = counts95['index'][i]
```

The code works but its not python friendly (using 4 for loops) and takes a huge amount of time to do the operation.
The main idea behind it is linking the records where the elements in list at **counts95['links']** is in any of the proceeding rows, if yes update the column **linksoflinks** with the index of first column only if **linksoflinks** column is None (no overwriting)

find the reference table below:

```
counts95 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [616351, 616352, 616353,6457754], 
                   'level0': [25,30,35,100],
                   'links' : [[1,2,3,4,5],[23,45,2],[1,19,67],[14,15,16]],
                   'linksoflinks' : [None,None,None,None]})
```

**EDIT:**
New Dataframe

```
counts95 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [616351, 616352, 616353,6457754,6566666,464664683], 
                   'level0': [25,30,35,100,200,556],
                   'links' : [[1,2,3,4,5],[23,45,2],[1,19,67],[14,15,16],[1,14],[14,1]],
                   'linksoflinks' : [None,None,None,None,None,None]})
```

Desired output:

```
     index  level0            links  linksoflinks
0   616351      25  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         NaN
1   616352      30      [23, 45, 2]    616351.0
2   616353      35      [1, 19, 67]    616351.0
3  6457754     100     [14, 15, 16]         NaN
4  6566666     200           [1,14]    616351.0
5  6457754     556           [14,1]    616351.0
```

Comment: kindly share data and not pics. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Edited the question to include reference table example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output uses different values and column name compare to your sample dataframe constructor. I use your desired output dataframe for testing.

**Logic:**
For each sublist of `links`, we need to find the row index(I mean index of the dataframe, NOT columns `index`) of the first overlapped sublist. We will use these row indices to slice by `.loc` on `counts95` to get corresponding values of column `index`. To achieve this goal we need to do several steps:

- Compare each sublist to all sublists in `link`. List comprehension is
  fast and efficient for this task. We need to code a list
  comprehension to create boolean 2D-mask array where each subarray
  contains `True` values for overlapped rows and `False` for non-overlapped(look at the step-by-step on this
  2D-mask and check with column `links` you will see clearer)
- We want to compare from top to the current sublist. I.e. standing
  from current row, we only want to compare backward to the top.
  Therefore, we need to set any forward-comparing to `False`. This is
  the functionality of `np.tril`
- Inside each subarray of this 2D-mask the position/index of `True` is 
  the row index of the row which the current sublist got overlapped. We need to find 
  these positions of `True`. It is the functionality of `np.argmax`.
  `np.argmax` returns the position/index of the first max element of the array. `True` is considered as `1` and `False` as `0`. Therefore,
  on any subarray having `True`, it correctly returns the 1st overlapped row index. However, on all `False` subarray, it    returns `0`. We will handle all `False` subarray later with `where`
- After `np.argmax`, the 2D-mask is reduce to 1D-mask. Each element of
  this 1D-mask is the number of row index of the overlapped sublist.
  Passing it to `.loc` to get corresponding values of column `index`.
  However, the result also wrongly includes row where subarray of
  2D-mask contains all `False`. We want these rows turn to `NaN`. It is
  the functionality of `.where`

**Method 1**:
Use list comprehension to construct the boolean 2D-mask `m` between each list of `links`  and the all lists in `links`. We only need backward-comparing, so use `np.tril` to crush upper right triangle of the mask to all `False` which represents forward-comparing. Finally, call `np.argmax` to get position of first `True` in each row of `m` and chaining `where` to turn all `False` row of `m` to `NaN`

```
c95_list = counts95.links.tolist()
m = np.tril([[any(x in l2 for x in l1) for l2 in c95_list] for l1 in c95_list],-1)
counts95['linkoflist'] = (counts95.loc[np.argmax(m, axis=1), 'index']
                                  .where(m.any(1)).to_numpy())

 Out[351]:
     index  level0            links  linkoflist
0   616351      25  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         NaN
1   616352      30      [23, 45, 2]    616351.0
2   616353      35      [1, 19, 67]    616351.0
3  6457754     100     [14, 15, 16]         NaN
4  6566666     200          [1, 14]    616351.0
5  6457754     556          [14, 1]    616351.0
```

---

**Method 2**:
If you dataframe is big, comparing each sublist to only top part of `links` makes it faster. It probably 2x faster method 1 on big dataframe.

```
c95_list = counts95.links.tolist()
m = [[any(x in l2 for x in l1) for l2 in c95_list[:i]] for i,l1 in enumerate(c95_list)]
counts95['linkoflist'] = counts95.reindex([np.argmax(y) if any(y) else np.nan 
                                                   for y in m])['index'].to_numpy()
```

---

**Step by Step(method 1)**

```
m = np.tril([[any(x in l2 for x in l1) for l2 in c95_list] for l1 in c95_list],-1)

Out[353]:
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

`argmax` returns position both first `True` and first `False` of all-`False` row.

```
In [354]: np.argmax(m, axis=1)
Out[354]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Slicing using the result of `argmax`

```
counts95.loc[np.argmax(m, axis=1), 'index']

Out[355]:
0    616351
0    616351
0    616351
0    616351
0    616351
0    616351
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Chain `where` to turn rows corresponding to all `False` from `m` to `NaN`

```
counts95.loc[np.argmax(m, axis=1), 'index'].where(m.any(1))

Out[356]:
0         NaN
0    616351.0
0    616351.0
0         NaN
0    616351.0
0    616351.0
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

Finally, the index of the output is different from the index of `counts95`, so just call `to_numpy` to get the ndarray to assign to the column `linkoflist` of `counts95`.

Comment: this got my loop down from 3 hours to 6 minutes for a total of 15000 rows. I know you have given a good explanation here, can you please add your overall logic for this to better understand the code, I would highly appreciate that and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Rishi: I added detail logic to the answer. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The good pattern would be using *proper data structures* for your task. The best choice on answering the question «is element X present in Y sequence» is the built-in `set`. When your sets are immutable, consider using `frozenset`.

## Solution

Here is how I would solve the problem in pythonic way:

```py
# necessary imports
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Tuple, FrozenSet, DefaultDict

# initialise the links "mapping": for every index save frozenset of its links
links: Tuple[Tuple[int, FrozenSet[int]]] = (
    # tuple of tuples is like a dict but will let you iterate by index
    (616351, frozenset((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))),
    (616352, frozenset((23, 45, 2))),
    (616353, frozenset((1, 19, 67))),
    (6457754, frozenset((14, 15, 16))),
)

# defaultdict automatically creates new lists
#   as you access its keys which are not yet present
links_of_links: DefaultDict[int, List[int]] = defaultdict(list)

for i, item in enumerate(links):
    key, values = item  # split tuple into individual elements
    next_rows = links[i+1:]  # we will iterate over succeeding rows
    for next_key, next_values in next_rows:
        # here we check sets intersection:
        #   it is non-empty if any common elements are present
        if values & next_values:
            # though key might not be present in links_of_links,
            #   defaultdict will autocreate a new empty list
            links_of_links[key].append(next_key)
```

Contents of links_of_links: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {616351: [616352, 616353]})`

## Complexity

Let's now compare the complexity of your solution and mine to prove latter is more efficient. Let's assume `N` is the number of rows and `L` is some sort of the length of links lists (average or maximum, it does not really matter). Your solutions compares roughly all rows pairs which gives us `O(N * N)`. This is then multiplied by complexity of naive comparison of two lists — `O(L * L)`. It gives us `O(N * L)²` in total.

The proposed solution still cross joins all the rows so `N * N` stays with us. But now we compare sets themselves in a more efficient way: `O(min(L, L)) === O(L)`, as [Python Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) says. So overall complexity is divided by single `L`, giving `O(N² * L)` as total.

Comment: This gives the desired output but how can I change my preexisting Dataframe to use frozensets?

Comment: @Rishi it seems to me that there is not problem using frozensets, pandas preserves its type: `pd.DataFrame({'x': frozenset([1, 2])}).iloc[0]['x']` is `frozenset({1, 2})`

Comment: with the updated data set in the question, this is not giving the desired output, I have also added a desired output to the Question for reference

Answer (score 0):

using `explode` and `duplicated` and `.map` to assign to duplicate link values but only the latter ones.

```
df = counts95.explode('links')


m = df[df.duplicated(subset=['links'],keep=False)].groupby('links')['index'].first()


df['link_above'] = df['links'].loc[df.duplicated(subset='links',keep='first')].map(m)



re_made_df = df.groupby(["index", "level0"]).agg(
    links=("links", list), linkoflist=("link_above", "first")).reset_index()


print(re_made_df)


     index  level0            links  linkoflist
0   616351      25  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         NaN
1   616352      30      [23, 45, 2]    616351.0
2   616353      35      [1, 19, 67]    616351.0
3  6457754     100     [14, 15, 16]         NaN
```

Comment: what is link_above here?

Comment: It's your column, I just used a dif name before recreating it @rishi

Comment: Can you explain this code a bit please, like a step by step process of what you are doing here, that could help me a lot. I see this working but I have to understand it, rather than just copy-pasting it.

Comment: @Rishi just in the middle of a project but will do, did it work with your solution? for now just print each line by line to see whats happening and read the docs for `explode` and `map` i'll get back to you soon

Comment: I changed the link_above to link, but the code doesn't work as reset_index() gives an error

Comment: Sorry @Rishi like a fool I copied in the code incorrectly..! can you re-check?

Comment: thanks for your help, but there is one problem, if there are repeating lists with two different indexes it gives an error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis, i am editing the question to add 2 more rows to the error can be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative where you can manipulate data more;

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

counts95 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [616351, 616352, 616353,6457754,6566666,464664683], 
                   'level0': [25,30,35,100,200,556],
                   'links' : [[1,2,3,4,5],[23,45,2],[1,19,67],[14,15,16],[1,14],[14,1]],
                   'linksoflinks' : [None,None,None,None,None,None]})

def has_match(ar1, ar2):
    return bool(set(ar1).intersection(ar2))

def set_linksoflinks(df):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        j = i+1
        while j<df.shape[0]:
            check = has_match(row['links'], df.loc[j, 'links'])
            if check and not df.loc[j, 'linksoflinks']:
                df.loc[j, 'linksoflinks'] = row['index']
            j+=1
    return df.copy()

df = set_linksoflinks(counts95)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       index  level0            links linksoflinks
0     616351      25  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         None
1     616352      30      [23, 45, 2]       616351
2     616353      35      [1, 19, 67]       616351
3    6457754     100     [14, 15, 16]         None
4    6566666     200          [1, 14]       616351
5  464664683     556          [14, 1]       616351
```

Comment: this is not the intended output, as the row 4 and 5 should have 616351, this is where we are marking duplicates with one value only

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the null check :). See edited answer.